# How can I use the default LightDM login screen with GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, login-screen

I would like to keep the normal Unity log-in screen and everything.

When I installed GNOME Shell, it seems to have replaced the log-in screen with the GNOME one.

I like jumping between different desktop environments, but I like the Unity log-in screen MUCH more.

Is there a way to only install the most recent GNOME desktop environment, without changing the login screen?

Comment: Why don't you just change the login manager back to lightDM? `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: @Seth♦
Yup, that fixed my problem, thanks so much!
Now I feel like a doofus...